# What is the best way to remove duplicate files on web hosting's FTP server?

Tags: ftp, web-hosting

For some reason(Happened before I started working on this project)- my client's website has 2 duplicates of every single file. Effectively tripling the size of the site.

The files look much like this:

```
wp-comments-post.php    |    3,982 bytes
wp-comments-post (john smith's conflicted copy 2012-01-12).php    |    3,982 bytes
wp-comments-post (JohnSmith's conflicted copy 2012-01-14).php    |    3,982 bytes
```

The hosting that the website is on has no access to bash or SSH.

In your opinion, what would be the easiest way to delete these duplicate files that would take the least time?

Comment: I didn't say this before, but the site has half a gig of files across many directories. I'm looking for a way to search for files with the string "conflicted copy" and delete them.

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be easier to start with a new, clean WordPress installation.  wp-comments-post.php is a standard WP file.  What are the other files that are dupes that make this idea unworkable? Alternatively, since you have no shell access, it might be easier to download everything from the hosting company, fix it locally, and push it back up as a new installation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I ended up just downloading the files locally, using windows to search and delete the files, then uploaded it back to the ftp server.

Comment: Do you know what is the name/version of the remote FTP server's engine? The commands available in that version will dictate the route to take...

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a duplicates finder script in PowerShell using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

*Up to date and enhanced version of this script is now available as WinSCP extension

[Find duplicate files in SFTP/FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_find_duplicate_files).*

The script first iterates a remote directory tree and looks for files with the same size. When it finds any, it by default downloads the files and compares them locally.

If you know, that the server supports a [protocol extension for calculating checksums](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols), you can improve the script efficiency by adding the `-remoteChecksumAlg` switch, to make the script ask the server for the checksum, sparing the file download.

```
powershell.exe -File find_duplicates.ps1 -sessionUrl ftp://user:password@example.com/ -remotePath /path
```

The script is:

```powershell
param (
    # Use Generate URL function to obtain a value for -sessionUrl parameter.
    $sessionUrl = "sftp://user:mypassword;fingerprint=ssh-rsa-xxxxxxxxx...=@example.com/",
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $remotePath,
    $remoteChecksumAlg = $Null
)

function FileChecksum ($remotePath)
{
    if (!($checksums.ContainsKey($remotePath)))
    {
        if ($remoteChecksumAlg -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "Downloading file $remotePath..."
            # Download file
            $localPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
            $transferResult = $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath)

            if ($transferResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($localPath)
                $checksum = [BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash($stream))
                $stream.Dispose()

                Write-Host "Downloaded file $remotePath checksum is $checksum"

                Remove-Item $localPath
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host ("Error downloading file ${remotePath}: " +
                    $transferResult.Failures[0])
                $checksum = $False
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Request checksum for file $remotePath..."
            $buf = $session.CalculateFileChecksum($remoteChecksumAlg, $remotePath)
            $checksum = [BitConverter]::ToString($buf)
            Write-Host "File $remotePath checksum is $checksum"
        }

        $checksums[$remotePath] = $checksum
    }

    return $checksums[$remotePath]
}

function FindDuplicatesInDirectory ($remotePath)
{
    Write-Host "Finding duplicates in directory $remotePath ..."

    try
    {
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

        foreach ($fileInfo in $directoryInfo.Files)
        {
            $remoteFilePath = ($remotePath + "/" + $fileInfo.Name) 

            if ($fileInfo.IsDirectory)
            {
                # Skip references to current and parent directories
                if (($fileInfo.Name -ne ".") -and
                    ($fileInfo.Name -ne ".."))
                {
                    # Recurse into subdirectories
                    FindDuplicatesInDirectory $remoteFilePath
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host ("Found file $($fileInfo.FullName) " +
                    "with size $($fileInfo.Length)")

                if ($sizes.ContainsKey($fileInfo.Length))
                {
                    $checksum = FileChecksum($remoteFilePath)

                    foreach ($otherFilePath in $sizes[$fileInfo.Length])
                    {
                        $otherChecksum = FileChecksum($otherFilePath)

                        if ($checksum -eq $otherChecksum)
                        {
                            Write-Host ("Checksums of files $remoteFilePath and " +
                                "$otherFilePath are identical")
                            $duplicates[$remoteFilePath] = $otherFilePath
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $sizes[$fileInfo.Length] = @()
                }

                $sizes[$fileInfo.Length] += $remoteFilePath
            }
        }
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host "Error processing directory ${remotePath}: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options from URL
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl)

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $session.SessionLogPath = "session.log"

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $sizes = @{}
        $checksums = @{}
        $duplicates = @{}

        $sha1 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1]::Create()

        # Start recursion
        FindDuplicatesInDirectory $remotePath
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    # Print results
    Write-Host

    if ($duplicates.Count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Duplicates found:"

        foreach ($path1 in $duplicates.Keys)
        {
            Write-Host "$path1 <=> $($duplicates[$path1])"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "No duplicates found."
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: use ftpfs to mount a remote ftp filesystem at a local mountpoint, then use any other approach detailed here.*

If all the files conform to that syntax, you could for example

```
rbos@chili:~/tmp$ touch asdf.php
rbos@chili:~/tmp$ touch "asdf (blah blah blah).php"
rbos@chili:~/tmp$ touch "asdf (blah blah rawr).php"
rbos@chili:~/tmp$ find | grep "(.*)"
./asdf (blah blah rawr).php
./asdf (blah blah blah).php
```

to match the files, and then just pipe that into xargs or a loop to check the list:

```
find | grep "(.*)" | while read i; do echo "$i";done | less
```

and then replace `echo` with `rm` once you're satisfied that the list is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) to find duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

FTP into the server and `rm` the files.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information- but there are too many to delete individually. Is there a way to search for a specific string and delete those files?

Comment: Too many to do by hand? Let me introduce you to the "intern"...

Comment: Too many to do individually? Seriously? Get a listing, process it into `rm` commands, then run the commands from your ftp client. What's the hard part?

Answer (score 0):

Run this: `find /yourdir -name "*conflicted copy*" -type f -ls`

If the files listed are the ones you want to delete, change `-ls` for `-delete` and run it again.

I suggest backuping your base dir first with tar before you do this...

EDIT: I just realized you do not have access to a shell session, so this won't work for you...

You would probably need something like this: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2348 to dump a list of files recursively, and then create another script that deletes the ones you want only.

Comment: You can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`  to avoid the fork() overhead.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that switch

Comment: This does't help the OP, given that he has no shell access.

Comment: Oops, dang, I missed that completely... Won't be easy then! I don't know of an FTP equivalent for the find command, and he'd need that to dump a whole list of duplicates recursively... Without that, he's out of luck.